# sql server table search for term in field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to create a script that will be usable on 10 tables with very much the same structure. I have to reference two columns in each table where the columns are
searchitem
feed
I need to search for each searchitem in its matching feed field and get a confirmation if it the field feed, contains it or not. I thought of using charindex but not sure if this would be appropriate and how to do it for each record.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(searchitem, feed)
FROM Production
WHERE not searchitem is null.
```

Just to clarify, I only need to apply the search to one table at a time, meaning search a table for where the searchitem value is in the feed value for all records in that table

Edits...

```
select id,searchterm,feed,
( Case
    When charindex(production.searchterm,production.feed) >= '1' then
     'yes' 
  else
     'no'
  END
) as Matchfound
from production
where production.searchterm is not null
```

searchterm = caixa

feed = A loja toda se assustou c a gentileza do garçon André Araújo. Era o jeito, pois toda hora a pessoa do caixa pedia 5minutos...Oiiiiiiiiiiiiii

Comment: What are the desired results? The matching row(s) or just a yes/no for each table?

Comment: you want to search columns in 10 tables for the same value?  and get a yes/no answer if it appears in any of the 10, or each of the 10?

Comment: yes, just a confirmation, displaying id, searchterm, feed, yes/no and only search one table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Production.*, (
  CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX(Production.searchitem,Production.feed) >= 1 THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
  END
) AS   MatchFound
FROM   Production
WHERE  Production.searchitem IS NOT NULL
```

Something like that perhaps? Appends a column to the end (`MatchFound`) flagging if the match was found in that column (with a `Yes` or `No`).

Comment: `CHARINDEX('abc','xyz')` is 0 not `NULL`. It will only return `NULL` if one of the operands is `NULL`.

Comment: @Martin: Touché. Did a test against a DB i have and forgot that if either expression are null the value is NULL. If not found, it's 0. Changing it now, good catch.

Comment: what is the select PRoduction.*,? for... I get it is not a valid built in function name is I leave the .* out

Comment: I am used to doing table joins and such where I need to explicitly mention the "source" table. As such, I did so in this example. You probably want to replace `Production.*,` with `id, searchterm, feed,` for your own purposes.

Comment: spoke to soon, the results are not correct. it is showing no for all even though when checked the field value contains the searchitem

Comment: It shouldn't be, worked fine in my scenario. You're going for exact match within, correct? And can you show an example of "feed" and "searchitem" in a case where it fails?

Comment: ok figured out the issue, there were spaces after each searchterm